# Editing content of CKEditor programmatically before submit

Tags: jquery, ckeditor4.x

I am having trouble editing the content of the ckeditor programmatically before submit.

I have a file input in my html and let the user upload an image. This image is being inserted into the ckeditor instance by doing

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].editable().insertHtml('<img class="image-content" width="350" height="450" src="' + image + '"' />');
```

Here the **image** variable is base64 byte string which gets pretty long. What I am trying to do is to get rid of **src** attribute from the img tag programmatically before submit. Below is what I attempted.

```
var content= CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].getData();
$(content).each(function (index, p) {
    if ($(p).find('img').length > 0) {
        $(p).find('img').each(function (index, img) {
            $(img).attr('src', '');
        });
    }
});
```

Based on what I found, the content of the ckeditor contains list of **p** tags.
So I loop through each **p** tag, check if it contains an **img** tag. If it does, replace its **src** arrtibute with empty string.

I checked the **content** by printing it after the inner most loop and it seems all **src** of each **img** tag has not been replaced with empty string.

Does anyone have an idea why this doesn't work? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Umm, shouldn't `p` & `img` be surrounded with quotes?

Comment: Documentation: https://origin-docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(content).find('p img').attr('src','');
```

...will remove the `src` attributes. Or even `.find('img')`, if you don't have any `<img>`s outside `<p>`s that need to keep their `src` attributes.

---

Potential problems with your code:

- you're using the same identifier (`index`) in two nested `.each()` calls. **Don't!** Use different iterators when nesting (`i`+`j`, `a`+`b`, `i0`+`i1`+...)
- the elements you pass as reference to `.each()` are already jQuery wrappers, you don't have to wrap them again. i.e:

```js
.each(function (index, p) {
  p.find('img')  // and not $(p).find('img') !
  ...
}
```

Comment: I made the content as an jquery instance and assigned to an extra variable as "var tmp = $(content);". Manipulating this "tmp" worked as I expected but I am not sure why. LOL Anyway, thanks for your answer. It helped.

Comment: It's because jQuery wrappers are not the same thing as the elements they wrap around. The `DOM` element is inside the `0` property of the wrapper, when the wrapper is not a collection of elements. Happy coding!